# Custom Gazebo world doesn't load

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a custom gazebo world for my turtleBot constaining several walls and saved it as a .world file. However when I run the world file using the command

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch world_file:=/home/PI/turtlebot_custom_gazebo_worlds/final1.world
```

the walls that i created do not load. just the turtlebot loads. the process in the terminal starts without giving any error. when i check the .world file the code related to the walls is clearly present.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277170/custom-gazebo-world-doesn%27t-load/) by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-12-03**:
Might be a bug in your world file. Can you post the file?

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-12-05**:
Maybe copying the model that represents the walls to `~/.gazebo` would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, silly mistake. The path to the world file was incorrect. It was not loading the custom world and just reverting to the default world without giving a traceback!

---

Originally posted by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) with karma: 18 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0